# How can I filter a list by different conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, logical-and

I've written the following code:

```
list_1 = [5, 18, 3]
list_2 = []
for element in list_1:
    if element < 0:
        list_2.append(element)
    elif element % 9 == 0:
        list_2.append(element)
    elif element % 2 != 0: 
        list_2.append(element)
    else:
        print('No number is valid')
print(list_2)
```

The problem is that this returns a list of numbers that satisfy at least one of the 3 conditions.

The result I want is a list of the numbers that satisfy all three conditions. How could I achieve that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `and`, actually. They said they want the elements to fulfil all 3 conditions.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: indeed, I hadn't read far enough there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes! But the problem is that with the `or`, the return obtained is the list with the numbers that satisfy at least one of the conditions. I want to know if it is possible to do the opposite, Get the list with the numbers that satisfy all the conditions at the same time.

Comment: Closely related, but probably not a good dupe: [Python's equivalent of && (logical-and) in an if-statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/2485466)

Comment: @Amartin: the opposite of `or` is `and`.

Comment: I've tidied up the question a bit, but I wasn't sure when you want "No number is valid" to be printed, so I left that bit out. Feel free to put that back in if it's important.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, the "No number is valid" is not important, is just a control if the conditions are not satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list comprehension :

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if i<0 and i%9==0 and i%2 !=0]
```

Comment: Hi, this works if the `or` is changed by `and` as @Martijn Pieters suggested

Answer (score 3):

Use a single if statement that combines all your conditions

```
if element<0 and element%9==0 and element%2!=0 :
    list2.append(element)
```

Comment: ups, sry for this. But the idea counts :D, didnt bother to look at his cases for too long

Comment: @kalehmann: I hadn't even read that far, I missed the addendum there.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the function `filter()` and `&` instead of `AND` (`|` instead of `OR`):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x < 0 & x % 9 == 0 & x % 2 != 0, list_1)
```